# overlapping hours in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, overlapping

I am dealing with a problem of overlapping hours. Story is like that - I have a website with bars and system which should show user which bar is opened right now. What is difficult is when I use method of checking the time in this current day I cannot because hours goes also to the next day. E.g. one pub is opening at 9 am and closing at 2 am the next day. How can I solve this, my code below - I get the times in JSON.

```
    var current_time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false, hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"});

    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  "sundayStart";
    weekday[1] = "mondayStart";
    weekday[2] = "tuesdayStart";
    weekday[3] = "wednesdayStart";
    weekday[4] = "thursdayStart";
    weekday[5] = "fridayStart";
    weekday[6] = "saturdayStart";
    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

    var weekday1 = new Array(7);
    weekday1[0]=  "sundayEnd";
    weekday1[1] = "mondayEnd";
    weekday1[2] = "tuesdayEnd";
    weekday1[3] = "wednesdayEnd";
    weekday1[4] = "thursdayEnd";
    weekday1[5] = "fridayEnd";
    weekday1[6] = "saturdayEnd";
    var m = weekday1[d.getDay()];
```

So, this code firstly checks which day is right now, and then finds values within START and END array values.  I cannot use between method because of that overlapping values in the next day. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please post a sample of the JSON data

Comment: If you create a Date for the start and end times, then you can simply compare with `<=` and `>=` to see if the current date is within range. Seeing the format of the dates in your source data will help with advice on parsing (don't leave it to the Date constructor or Date.parse).

Comment: You could also express the open and close times as an opening time and duration, so open at 09:00 for 17:00 gives 9am to 2am the following day.

Comment: Here it is 
`"openHours": {
        "fridayStart": "08:00",
        "fridayEnd": "03:00"
}`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have multiple ranges for each day, so they don't cross over midnight. So instead of saying that it opens on Monday from 9am to 2am, and Tuesday from 10am to 3am, do it like:

```
Monday: 09:00 - 23:59
Tuesday: 00:00 - 02:00, 10:00-23:59
Wednesday: 00:00 - 03:00
```

So each day of the week would have an array of `{open: xxx, close: xxx}` objects. You loop through all the objects for the current day, and return `true` if the current time is in any of the ranges.

If your input JSON isn't like this, you can create it by processing the input. Whenever the close time is less than the open time, split it up into two ranges. The first range is from the open time to `23:59` on the same day, the second range is from `00:00` to the close time on the next day.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to express the open and close times as a start and duration, so if bar1 opens at 9am and closes at 2am the following day and bar 2 opens at 3pm and closes at 6:30am the following day, you'd have:

1. bar1: 09:00, 17:00
2. bar2: 15:00, 15:30

```js
var times = {bar1: ['09:00', '17:00'], bar2: ['15:00', '15:30']};

function showBarTimes(data) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(bar) {
    var open = new Date();
    var openTime = times[bar][0].split(':');
    var duration = times[bar][1].split(':');
    open.setHours(openTime[0], openTime[1], 0,0);
    var close = new Date(+open);
    close.setHours(close.getHours() + +duration[0], close.getMinutes() + +duration[1]);
    var now = new Date();
    var currentlyOpen = now >= open && now <= close;

    console.log(bar + ' opens at ' +
                open.toLocaleString() + ' and closes at ' +
                close.toLocaleString() + ' and is currently ' + 
                (currentlyOpen? 'OPEN':'CLOSED'));
  });
}
showBarTimes(times);
```

Comment: Hi, good idea but how can I express that duration ? E.g. here is friday with end time already in saturday. 
`"openHours": { "fridayStart": "08:00", "fridayEnd": "03:00" }`

Comment: Since you've now shown how the data is provided, you might assume that if the end time is earlier than the start time that it must be the following day. But it also seems you want to match on the day name as well. That adds a another layer of logic (e.g. *fridayEnd* overlaps to Saturday). I think what you have in answers is sufficient for you to have a go and post some code of your own.